why the style error and chinese is not display when i use itext7 pdfhtml java lib translate svg to pdf
Initially, I utilized an SVG as a background image in the CSS of my HTML file and attempted to convert it to PDF using HtmlConvert.convertToPdf. However, my SVG images are experiencing styling issues where the colors are inverted, showing black as white and vice versa, and moreover, Chinese characters fail to display properly. I encountered limitations with html2pdf's support for SVG. Subsequently, I tried converting the SVG directly to PDF using SvgConvert.createPdf, only to find that the SVG still presented similar issues. This leads me to believe that there might be inadequate support for SVG processing, regardless of the method used. Here is my code:
SvgConverterProperties prop = new SvgConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
PdfFont pdfFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/font/HYWenHei-75W.ttf,PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H");
fontProvider.addFont(pdfFont.getFontProgram());
prop.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
SvgConvert.createPdf(new FileInputStream('test.svg'),new FileOutPutStream('test.pdf'),prop);

the svg file like text
I'm not sure if this is a bug; could someone please help me with this? Thank you.
Is there a solution from the user's coding perspective to address this issue, or could developers resolve it and release an update? Please assist with this.

I was able to minimize the input .svg to
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-v-4b6fc447="" width="692px" height="125px" viewBox="0 0 692 125" version="1.1">
  <defs >
    <radialGradient  cx="12.1963505%" cy="29.0520353%" fx="12.1963505%" fy="29.0520353%" r="93.5585522%" gradientTransform="translate(0.122, 0.2905), scale(0.9529, 1), rotate(39.6312), scale(1, 0.6811), translate(-0.122, -0.2905)" id="radialGradient-20">
      <stop stop-color="#FFE6D4" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="24.9044735%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="29.1362898%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="62.7690476%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#C8DEF9" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path data-v-4b6fc447="" d="M21.7423222,60.6707778 C19.9989592,60.2319973 11.0239174,55.753224 10.4824503,55.4581759 C0.269863617,50.4946798 0.798100889,45.3473504 0.798100889,40.9353539 C0.798100889,36.3395242 2.03065446,32.1113609 4.3196825,28.2508639 C5.62436175,26.2181404 7.00454795,24.4314687 8.42607253,22.8611664 C8.84671997,22.0277824 9.79720103,17.0616363 12.8561581,12.0244345 L18.4999935,15.0858947 C26.3198285,11.0937275 33.0205726,11.5220436 33.0205726,11.5220436 C33.4942723,11.5355932 33.9603196,11.5563833 34.4187232,11.5839446 C35.913608,10.2265004 36.0621399,9.5903757 35.7800241,7.09428014 C34.0533999,5.88182307 34.3029078,4.01911942 34.3029078,3.87421871 C34.3029078,2.90566404 34.6840946,1.93710936 35.446468,1.16226563 C36.2088415,0.3874219 37.1618084,0 38.1147751,0 C40.2113021,0 41.9266425,1.74339848 41.9266425,3.87421871 C41.9266425,6.00503895 40.2113021,7.7484375 38.1147751,7.7484375 C38.658364,9.49167078 38.6004157,10.3520544 38.4881948,12.0260966 C44.0393929,12.9078672 48.1986819,14.7583091 50.9894527,16.4199693 C52.6950942,15.4064503 53.5295649,14.1357205 56.5120729,12.5347571 C58.9839274,16.1877668 60.3758122,20.8249462 60.6877275,26.4462954 C62.5491203,29.2966742 63.9619936,32.4476068 64.8908861,35.7880247 C66.1234397,43.1413522 64.0104907,47.0018492 64.0104907,47.0018492 C60.9416839,53.9437406 50.1142623,58.4727808 49.4298997,58.7533428 L49.3959271,58.7671733 C48.6841697,58.998589 48.16522,59.1602579 47.8390779,59.2521801 C46.8307435,59.5363761 39.8013407,61.1207721 32.8769409,61.3903217 C28.2606744,61.5700214 24.5491348,61.3301735 21.7423222,60.6707778 Z" 
      id="path-21"/>


  </defs>
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" >
    <g stroke="none" >
      <use  fill="url(#radialGradient-20)" xlink:href="#path-21"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

And i have found that iText hasn't supported radialGradient yet, see
https://github.com/itext/itext-java/blob/develop/svg/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/svg/renderers/factories/DefaultSvgNodeRendererMapper.java#L159
If you clean up your svg from ignored SVG tags, you will get acceptable result.
About

Chinese characters fail to display properly

I will be able to say more, if you provide a HYWenHei-75W.ttf font file.
